# Do I need to call Javascript Isolation (import) in my Razor page?

Tags: blazor, razor-pages

I have Blazor project, I already create a CSS isolation page & it work I dont need to call it.So now I need to use Javascript in Razor page so I create razor.js [this is what I create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd003.png)

1. I want to know do I need to import or call my js in my razor page ?
   because it seem my script did'nt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not call javascript in your razor page like css solation (what you did), In .Net core 3 you need to reference all your javascript files inside _Host.cshtml file and in razor pages you can call the functions via IJSRuntime. In .NET 5 it improved, Now you can load your js file wherever you need and then call the functions.
Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-javascript-isolation-and-object-references) document in Microsoft doc.